# Naukris login button, not able to click

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I was trying to automate resume upload procedure for naukri.com, but unable to click on naukris home button. Its not iframe as well.

website :https://login.naukri.com/nLogin/Login.php

Code used :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//[@id='emailTxt']")).sendKeys(userName);
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='pwd1']")).sendKeys(password);
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='sbtLog']")).click();
```

Comment: You shouldn't put username and password in a question.

Answer (score 0):

There are two element with `id='sbtLog'`, the driver finds the first one and click on it, but you need the second one. Look for an element with this `id` that also has attribute `name='Login'`

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='sbtLog' and @name='Login']")).click();
```